# Is there a way to find the URL to a database from within MySQLAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, url

It seems like this may have been asked a thousand times, but I can't find anything on search. Forgive me if I overlooked anything.

Anyway, I'm working on a website with a terrible admin section. The one I'm used to allows you to set the url of your database so you can link to it, this one does not.

So my question is, is there a way, from within mySQLadmin to find the URL to a database you are working on?

---

I need to connect to the database for PHP stuff.

Comment: The address of your database is most likely going to be found in your hosting control panel...

Comment: Chris, that's the problem, it's setup pretty pretty bad. the only URL it lists is universal for all databases and it doesn't work.

I realize there should be other ways to get the URL but they aren't available. I am trying to ask specifically if anyone knows a way to get it via mySQLadmin/phpMyadmin.

Comment: What do you mean by “URL to the database”? Do you actually mean the _host name_ of the database server …?

Comment: Yes, I do mean the host name.